# Getting oauth_verifier in twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to make an application in c# which will interact with Tweeter...

I have done something like below..

```
public void Authorize()
    {
        TwitterService service = new TwitterService("key","secret");
        OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();
        var oauthtoken = requestToken.Token;
        var oauthsecret = requestToken.TokenSecret;
        Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
        AuthorizeCallback(oauthtoken,oauthverifier);
    }

public void AuthorizeCallback(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier)
    {
        var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauth_token };

        TwitterService service = new TwitterService("key","secret");
        OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);
    }
```

Now my question is from where can i get the oauth_verifier?

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines at the beginning of your callback function.

```
string OauthToken = Request.QueryString["oauth_token"];

string OauthVerifier = Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];
```

Comment: var VerifyPin = AuthorizeResult["oauth_verifier"];...here oaauth_verifier is null, its giving me error